# In what situations is a formula faster than Olog(n) if statements

Tags: arrays, data-structures, time-complexity

My goal is to make a data structure with a very fast or constant resize cost.

To do this I am simply making a list of pointers that point to the starts of arrays of base^index size. where base = some arbitrary constant.

However I want to access this like a normal array. I can prove that the access time is constant, but to get the array element the formula would be something along the lines of

```
pointer index = min(log*base*((1+index)(1-base)/base)
array index = index - (base(1-base^pointerindex)/(1-base))
```

In this scenario, would it be faster to make a while loop that runs in O(log(n)) time?

```
while (index > arrayLength)
    prevLength = arraylength
    arraylength += arrays[i].length
    i++
    pointerindex = i

then 

arrayindex = index - prevLength
```

My thinking is division and log and exponentiation are expensive operations, some can't even be done in log(n) time. So at what point would a simple while loop beat them out?

Also Does anyone know what this data structure is called? I Doubt I'm the first person to come up with this

Comment: Store the cumulative array lengths to array index mapping in a balanced tree. The number of arrays is log(n), so lookups in the tree will be O(log(log(n))).

Comment: @Welbog `O(log(log(n))` is going to have more complex code, but since most array-like structures contain < 1 million elements, there's only <20 pointers to iterate over, so the iteration is probably faster. But if the pointer-array also contains the lengths, then he also get cache hits as well. very fast.

Comment: My idea was to maximize cache hits as much as I possibly could, while making a quick resizable array. I'm trying to Implement a cache efficient fibbonacci heap. But to do that i need a quickely resizable array. Cache efficient is preserved Per Array. And an additional list of the first indexes of each array is also kept. im trying to keep the ratio of wasted space as low as possible without having crazy resize times.
A nonresizable array would have 2^index-1.6^index worst case, which is just 2^index growth. It quickely gets rediculus.